# Input flickers on ng-if

Tags: html, angularjs, input

Hi I've got follow code:

```css
.container2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
}
.myClass1 {
  color: red;
}
.myClass2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js">
  </script>

  <script>
    angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {

    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container1">
    <input ng-if="!isOpen" type="text" placeholder="Text...">
    <span ng-if="!isOpen">Text1</span>
    <span ng-if="!isOpen">Text2</span>
    <span ng-if="isOpen">Text, when container 2 is open</span>
    <button class="myClass1" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen" ng-class="{myClass2: isOpen}">Click here...</button>

  </div>

  <div class="container2" ng-show="isOpen">Container 2 is open now...</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I builded a small example in my code snippet which shows the same logic as my solution. Here in the snippet it works fine (the code is really the same), but in my real solution, when I click on the button, it hides liquid the "Text 1" and "Text 2", shows the "Text when cont 2 is open", but the input waits a little bit and then it's also hidden. When I close it again all elements show and hide liquid...By opening, the input flickers and then hides...I try to show it to you with the images bellow:

- The two Icons are my spans "Text 1" and "Text 2"
- The triangle is my button

Step 1: Default it's closed and the three elements are there, the other one not:
[image]

Step 2: I click on the button, it should hide 3 elements and show one text, but for perhaps 0.5s the input stays there, flickers and than hides - for 0.5 seconds it looks like this:

[image]

Step 3: After it flickers for 0.5s it hides and than its correct like this:

[image]

I hope this is clear enough. Has someone an idea? Thanks and cheers.

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** It flickers with every form-element such as input, select, checkbox etc. When I put a div around the input and give the ng-if expression to the div, it works fine..

Comment: are you sure you don't have any css transitions on your input tags?

Comment: Yes this is my css for the input below: input {height: 30px; padding-left: 5px; text-align: left;} - Cheers

Comment: can you try to recreate the issue in a fiddle or plunkr? or some other working code

Comment: I tried it in a fiddle and in the stackoverflow code snippet, but no chance..

Comment: But in worse case I will put the div around and the ng-if on the div..Than it works..

Comment: it means there is something else in your code which is causing this, unless we can see that or recreate that it might be difficult to pinpoint

Comment: I now what you mean, I hoped, that perhaps such problems with ng-show/hide/if on form-elements are known and tried it like this to get an answer. But for me it's a little bit weared, that this problem just exists on the form-elements. Any other element works fine...

Comment: So now is clear, that the problem will be something in my code.. This brings me forward thanks! I will inform you if I solve the problem.. Cheers

Comment: @gaurav5430 The ng-show solved my problem (after an ctrl-f5 reload). Look at the answer below (marked as correct). Cheers.

Comment: @gaurav5430 You're answer was right  - it was a transition on all inputs (css: html, input) which I did'nt saw... When I set the transition to none on this input it works with ng-if, ng-show and ng-hide. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ng-show despite of ng-if that may work beacuse ng-if removes dom element but ng-show doesnot actually remove dom element it just hides the dome element

That flickering may be due to the reason that dom element is removed

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer! I tried the ng-show and ng-hide before, it also flickers...With the div around it doesnt flicker, and any other element also don't flicker, just the form-elements..

Comment: PS: You are right with using the ng-show in case of ng-if because of removing. I will change this, because the code is better, but the flickering is still there...In worse case I'll put the div around and the ng-show on the div, so the flickering stops...

Comment: This solved my problem after a ctrl-f5 reload! Thanks and Cheers.

Comment: And I had to remove a transition for all inputs on this specifique input...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
.ng-hide.ng-hide-animate {
display: none !important;
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14015